My custom ScrapeFileOptionDialog window is showing twice
My custom dialog is showing twice when I either close the first window popup, after I close it midway, or after it saves the results to Excel. I have a feeling that I am calling it accidentally wrong somehow. Any pointers to where I am going wrong and why this is occurring will greatly help me with my research.
Here is the ScrapeFileButton_Click code:
    ' Event handler for the scrape file button click event
Private Sub ScrapeFileButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles scrapeFileButton.Click
    Dim optionsDialog As New ScrapeFileOptionsDialog()
    Dim optionsResult As DialogResult = optionsDialog.ShowDialog()

    If optionsResult = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim searchTerm As String = InputBox("Enter the search term:")

        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid search term.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return
        End If

        If optionsDialog.ScrapeSingleFile Then
            ' User chose to scrape a single file
            Dim openFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog With {
            .Filter = "Supported Files|*.docx;*.htm;*.html;*.pdf",
            .Title = "Select File(s)",
            .Multiselect = False ' Allow selecting only one file
        }

            If openFileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim filePath As String = openFileDialog.FileName
                Dim fileType = Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower()

                Select Case fileType
                    Case ".docx"
                        ProcessWordDocument(filePath, searchTerm)
                    Case ".htm", ".html"
                        ProcessHtmlFile(filePath, searchTerm)
                    Case ".pdf"
                        ProcessPdfFile(filePath, searchTerm)
                    Case Else
                        MessageBox.Show("File type not supported.")
                End Select

                SaveToExcel() ' Save results after processing the selected file
            End If
        ElseIf optionsDialog.ScrapeEntireFolder Then
            ' User chose to scrape an entire folder
            Dim folderBrowserDialog As New FolderBrowserDialog With {
            .Description = "Select Folder",
            .ShowNewFolderButton = False
        }

            If folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim folderPath As String = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath
                Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath)

                For Each filePath In files
                    Dim fileType = Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower()

                    Select Case fileType
                        Case ".docx"
                            ProcessWordDocument(filePath, searchTerm)
                        Case ".htm", ".html"
                            ProcessHtmlFile(filePath, searchTerm)
                        Case ".pdf"
                            ProcessPdfFile(filePath, searchTerm)
                        Case Else
                            MessageBox.Show("File type not supported.")
                    End Select
                Next

                SaveToExcel() ' Save results after processing all files in the folder
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

I think it is going wrong in this method/handler. I have looked at other methods and initializers and can't seem to see a problem with others. Thanks in advance.

I can only see one place that you're displaying a ScrapeFileOptionsDialog form in that code and I wouldn't expect that that code would be executed twice. You need to debug your code. Put some breakpoints in appropriate places and step through the code to see what path of execution it takes. You could start by placing a breakpoint on that ShowDialog call, just to confirm it's not being made twice.

Awesome, I found what was causing it. It was due to the 'X' button there wasn't an event handler for the close button only OK and Cancel and for some reason the X was making it repeat the ShowDialog button twice.

Can you up vote this question?

You should not leave a resolved question unanswered. Ideally, you should provide your own answer and, assuming you can, accept it. That way, everyone can see that an accepted answer has been posted without even opening it. If you're not prepared to do that, you should delete the question.

The fix is that I was assuming that the close (X) on top of the Form had the same handler as the 'cancel' button on the dialog. Once I added logic for the close function to operate it stopped repeating the ShowDialog option.
